# How do I show the complete webpage title in a Safari tab?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

In Safari, I would like tab elements in the tab bar to be as long as the website title, so the whole page title is visible.

I have already selected “show page titles” in Preferences which shows part of the title.

Is there any extension to allow this?

Comment: I don't think that's configurable but it may help if you display tabs in a grid with View > Show Tab Overview (Shift-Command-\).